# Benefits of Office 365 over free OneDrive

Tags: onedrive, office365

Are there any limits/caveats to creating Office documents for free on OneDrive?
Does Office 365 have anything extra if all you need is basic Word/Excel?

Comment: this question will have primarily opinion based answers and is off topic for superuser.

Comment: it's not about opinions.  I'm making sure I'm not missing something that I couldn't find/search online.  If there are no caveats with creating Office files with OneDrive, then I will not sign up for 365.  I'm just asking to make sure there are no issues.  I updated my question for the purists.

Comment: If you don't need to be able to edit a word document online then not having that ability by not subscribing to Office 365 isn't a problem.  I suggest you do some more research on the differences we can't tell you if you need the capabilities of a paid Office 365 subscription or not.

Comment: Is it really that hard to find? http://products.office.com/en-us/compare-microsoft-office-products or http://products.office.com/en-us/business/compare-more-office-365-for-business-plans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can  create files using Onedrive when you are connected to internet but I believe it is not possible to create a word file when you don't have access to internet connection

Comment: Office 365 gives you unlimited storage.